# Efficiently detect if a device will play silent videos that have the autoplay attribute

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-chrome, html5-video

With Chrome 53 and iOS 10 both out now, there are now Android and iOS devices that are capable of automatically playing videos that are silent and have the `autoplay` attribute. I'd like to know how to detect this with JavaScript.

For Chrome 53, the `<video>` must have the `autoplay` and `muted` attributes (yes, the `muted` attribute is required even if the video file doesn't have any audio tracks).

For iOS 10, the `<video>` must have the `autoplay` attribute and, for non-iPad iOS 10 devices, the `playsinline` attribute too (yes, it must be `playsinline`; `webkit-playsinline` won't work).

So a `<video>` will automatically play in both Chrome 53 and iOS 10 (including non-iPad iOS 10 devices) if it has all three attributes: `autoplay`, `muted`, and `playsinline`.

If I were just interested in detecting this on iOS 10 devices, the code would be quite simple. I'm using jQuery, but this could easily be converted into vanilla JavaScript:

```
var muted_videos_autoplay = false;

$('<video playsinline>').on('play', function() {
  muted_videos_autoplay = true;
})[0].play();

setTimeout(function() {
  alert('muted_videos_autoplay: ' + muted_videos_autoplay);
}, 300);
```

But on Chrome 53, the only way I've found to do it is quite complicated:

```
var muted_videos_autoplay = false;

$('<video autoplay muted style="position: fixed; top: 0; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none;" src="data:video/mp4;base64, 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">').on('play', function() {
  muted_videos_autoplay = true;
  $(this).remove();
}).appendTo('body');

setTimeout(function() {
  alert('muted_videos_autoplay: ' + muted_videos_autoplay);
}, 300);
```

For the record, I got the video source from [here](https://github.com/kud/blank-video).

I could make the Chrome 53 code work for all iOS 10 devices too simply by adding the `playsinline` attribute onto the `<video>` that gets appended to the `<body>`. But I'd like to find a more efficient way to detect this behavior, if possible. Does anybody know of one?

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve? Check attributes at element `html`?

Comment: Chromes play function returns a promise (not sure if that's also in the 53 update or how long it's happened) - [this code](https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/gh-pages/video/scripted/index.html) may be of use to you - in fact there's possibly a lot of useful stuff in https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/tree/gh-pages/video

Comment: @guest271314 An example would be to perform the detection and, if the browser is capable of playing silent videos automatically, show a silent video slide show. Otherwise, show a still image slide show.

Comment: _"if the browser is capable of playing silent videos automatically"_ You can set `.volume` to `0` at `canplay` event.

Answer (score 4):

You can detect video autoplay support by checking if the paused status of a video element changes after it programmatically plays. This alone can return false negatives in some mobile browsers, so a Promise check should be added in order to cover these.

This method works in all major browsers (desktop and mobile), except for Android <= 4.0 and Windows Phone, where it returns a false negative.

Here is the detect function:

```js
var supports_video_autoplay = function(callback) {

  if (typeof callback !== "function") return false;

  var v = document.createElement("video");
  v.paused = true;
  var p = "play" in v && v.play();

  callback(!v.paused || ("Promise" in window && p instanceof Promise));

};
```

Usage:

```js
supports_video_autoplay(function(supported) {
  if (supported) {
    // video autoplay supported!
  } else {
    // no video autoplay support :(
  }
});
```

Live test: https://codepen.io/paulorely/pen/QveEGy